# Add new column DataFrame Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I try work with SparkSQL by adding a new column in dataframe

My Code is :

```
val df= sc.read.json("C:/Users/A661758/Desktop/TEST-XSLT.json")
df.withColumn("UID", new org.apache.spark.sql.Column("UID"))
```

Error :
**cannot resolve '`UID`' given input columns:**

I use Spark 2.1.0 and Scala 2.11.8

Thank you.

Comment: Is that `sc` or `sqlContext` ? check `df.printSchema()` for column presence.

Comment: The solution of this problem is :   df.withColumn("UID", lit("UID"));

Comment: that's not really the solution to the problem you described... that will just add a new column and fill it with "UID"... suggest you refine the question and describe the desired contents of the new column.

Comment: I want put in this column a value of type int :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add new column for existing dataframe you need to use withcolumn option.

New column with string type ,try this

```
df.withColumn("UID", lit("value").cast(StringType))
```

New column with integertype , try this

```
    df.withColumn("UID", lit("1").cast(IntegerType))
```

New column with auto increment number integertype ,try this

```
      df.withColumn("RowID",monotonicallyIncreasingId.cast(IntegerType))
```